# How to create xml plist for Xcode from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: xml, excel, xcode, plist

I have a spreadsheet, the contents of which I would like to include as an xml plist in my Xcode project. However, I can't figure out how to actually perform the export from Excel and the import into Xcode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to generate rather complex XML from Access, and after looking at various solutions, I found that the simplest (by far !) was to generate text files using my own functions.

You can find them on [my blog](http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2009/09/generer-du-xml-depuis-vba.html). I tried to paste them here, but Stackoverflow formatting system seems to eat some characters, like the greater than, or lower than, which made my code unreadable here.